# Text is messed up when writing RTL (Arabic) with English in between

Tags: wordpress, blog, text, css

Whenever I try to write an English word in an Arabic paragraph in WordPress it becomes like this:

```
بواسطة متجر Microsoft الإكتروني الرقمي
```

where it should be like this:

```
 الإلكتروني الرقمي Microsoft بواسطة متجر
```

The problem is in both the text editor and the theme (doing page Preview/live).

The theme I have supports RTL. I installed both TinyMCE and WP RTL without success. I was told it may be fixed with CSS editor for the theme but I'm totally clueless when it comes to programming (if I may call it that).

Answer (score 1):

The way I fix it only in the live page is by adding a special tag to each Arabic post (for example tag arabic) then in theme CSS I add:

```
tag-arabic {
direction: rtl;
}
```

You can add that CSS line through your theme (most new theme settings have a page where you can add custom CSS).

For the WYSIWYG text editor, you can use this plugin:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/contents-direction/

Comment: Welcome to WebApps. I formatted the code snippet: see [formatting help](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/formatting). Since the answer field is reserved for answers only, I edited the part of your post that looked more like a question.